# Descobrir qual o digito verificador de um CNPJ

Tags: c#, .net, validação

Tenho uma classe onde eu consigo descobrir se o CNPJ digitado pelo usuário é valido ou não.

O que eu gostaria de fazer, e que não estou conseguindo, é mostrar para o usuário quais são os dois últimos dígitos válidos que ele deveria digitar.

Por exemplo:

```
MessageBox("CNPJ inválido, o Digito Verificador correto seria: "+DV);
```

Gostaria de fazer isso para o CNPJ e CPF.

O método de validação do CNPJ é o seguinte:

```
public bool ValidaCNPJ(string vrCNPJ)
    {
        int nrDig;
        string CNPJ = vrCNPJ.Replace(".", "");
        CNPJ = CNPJ.Replace("/", "");
        CNPJ = CNPJ.Replace("-", "");

        string ftmt = "6543298765432";
        int[] digitos = new int[14];
        int[] soma = new int[2];
        soma[0] = 0;
        soma[1] = 0;
        int[] resultado = new int[2];
        resultado[0] = 0;
        resultado[1] = 0;
        bool[] CNPJOk = new bool[2];
        CNPJOk[0] = false;
        CNPJOk[1] = false;

        try
        {
            for (nrDig = 0; nrDig < 14; nrDig++)
            {
                digitos[nrDig] = int.Parse(
                 CNPJ.Substring(nrDig, 1));
                if (nrDig <= 11)
                    soma[0] += (digitos[nrDig] *
                    int.Parse(ftmt.Substring(
                      nrDig + 1, 1)));
                if (nrDig <= 12)
                    soma[1] += (digitos[nrDig] *
                    int.Parse(ftmt.Substring(
                      nrDig, 1)));
            }

            for (nrDig = 0; nrDig < 2; nrDig++)
            {
                resultado[nrDig] = (soma[nrDig] % 11);
                if ((resultado[nrDig] == 0) || (resultado[nrDig] == 1))
                    CNPJOk[nrDig] = (
                    digitos[12 + nrDig] == 0);

                else
                    CNPJOk[nrDig] = (
                    digitos[12 + nrDig] == (
                    11 - resultado[nrDig]));

            }

            return (CNPJOk[0] && CNPJOk[1]);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Método para validar CPF

```
public bool ValidaCpf(string cpf)
{

    int[] multiplicador1 = new int[9] { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
    int[] multiplicador2 = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
    string tempCpf;
    string digito;

    int soma;
    int resto;

    cpf = cpf.Trim();
    cpf = cpf.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");

    if (cpf.Length != 11)
    {
        return false;
    }
    tempCpf = cpf.Substring(0, 9);

    soma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * (multiplicador1[i]);
    }
    resto = soma % 11;

    if (resto < 2)
    {
        resto = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        resto = 11 - resto;
    }

    digito = resto.ToString();
    tempCpf = tempCpf + digito;
    int soma2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        soma2 += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];
    }

    resto = soma2 % 11;

    if (resto < 2)
    {
        resto = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        resto = 11 - resto;
    }

    digito = digito + resto.ToString();
    return cpf.EndsWith(digito);
}
```

Comment: Não entendo por que quer dar essa informação ao utilizador. Os dígitos de verificação servem para confirmar se não houve engano ao digitar qualquer um dos dígitos do CNPJ e não apenas os dois últimos. Aquilo que me parece que está a sugerir é querer dizer ao utilizador para alterar os últimos dois dígitos. O CNPJ será válido mas de certeza não será o do utilizador.

Comment: Sim @ramaral, gostaria de dizer para o usuario alterar os dois ultimos digitos, mas pensei em dizer para ele quais seria os corretos.
Claro que assim o cara vai poder burlar o sistema com o cnpj que não existe, mas é so uma opção amais que gostaria de disponibilizar para ele. E de aprendizagem tambem!

Comment: @EmersonMoraes, você fala em toda pergunta em CNPJ, mas seu exemplo é de CPF, recomendo substituir onde você cita CNPJ por CPF, ou vice-versa.

Comment: Desculpa @Fernando, acabei copiando o codigo errado. Vou colocar o de CNPJ tbm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenar de não ver muita utilidade na sua implementação final, como citado dos comentários de @ramaral, vou lhe ajudar no problema em si.

Você pode utilizar os [parâmetros out do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645764(v=vs.71).aspx), para recuperar do método de validação os dígitos verificadores, onde a implementação, seria algo assim (há comentários nas linhas alteradas):

```
// adicione o paramêtro out string dv
public bool ValidaCpf(string cpf, out string dv)
{
    int[] multiplicador1 = new int[9] { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
    int[] multiplicador2 = new int[10] { 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
    string tempCpf;
    string digito;

    int soma;
    int resto;

    cpf = cpf.Trim();
    cpf = cpf.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "");

    if (cpf.Length != 11)
    {
        // adicione essa linha, onde você seta o parâmetro out dv, com null, para fins de compilação, já que não há valor a ser adicionado, ou se acha melhor pode adicionar qualquer outro valor default.
        dv = null;
        return false;
    }
    tempCpf = cpf.Substring(0, 9);

    soma = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        soma += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * (multiplicador1[i]);
    }
    resto = soma % 11;

    if (resto < 2)
    {
        resto = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        resto = 11 - resto;
    }

    digito = resto.ToString();
    tempCpf = tempCpf + digito;
    int soma2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        soma2 += int.Parse(tempCpf[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];
    }

    resto = soma2 % 11;

    if (resto < 2)
    {
        resto = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        resto = 11 - resto;
    }

    digito = digito + resto.ToString();

    // adicione essa linha, onde você seta o parâmetro out dv, com o digito verificador valido
    dv = digito;
    return cpf.EndsWith(digito);
}
```

Onde um exemplo de utilização seria esse:

```
public void TestUtilizacao()
{
    string dv = null;
    string cpf = "12345678901";
    if(ValidaCpf(cpf, out dv))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CPF valido");
    }else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CPF inválido, o Digito Verificador correto seria: " + dv);
    }
}
```

O resultado do teste de utilização seria "CPF inválido, o Digito Verificador correto seria: 09".

Comment: O CNPJ é a mesma coisa neh...?

Comment: @EmersonMoraes, sim mesma ideia, só não identifiquei seu digito verificados no seu método de validação de CNPJ. (Ele me parece um pouco enrolado, hehe)

Comment: consegui os dois... O CNPJ é a mesma base de como vc fez o CPF. Muito obrigado pela ajuda xD

Answer (score 3):

Resolvi responder porque a resposta aceita não faz o CNPJ como pedido na pergunta, e ambas são ineficientes, ainda que certas, fora que são copiadas de um código amplamente usado, mas que deveriam citar a fonte (nem me arrisco dizer qual é). Eu sei que é um código mais complexo, mas ele pode ser usado onde precisa executar em grande quantidade sem problemas.

Reforço o que já foi dito que a intenção da pergunta não é boa.

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

(var ok, var digitos) = ValidarCnpj("12345678901234");
if (!ok) WriteLine($"Dígitos finais corretos seriam {digitos}");
(ok, digitos) = ValidarCnpj("12.345.678.9012-34");
if (!ok) WriteLine($"Dígitos finais corretos seriam {digitos}");

static (bool, string) ValidarCnpj(string cnpj) {
    if (cnpj.Length < 14) return (false, "");
    Span<int> digitos = stackalloc int[14];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 14; j++) if (char.IsDigit(cnpj[j])) digitos[i++] = cnpj[j] - 48;
    int soma = 0, soma2 = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        soma += digitos[i] * (5 - i);
        soma2 += digitos[i] * (6 - i);
    }
    soma2 += digitos[4] * 2;
    for (var i = 4; i < 11; i++) {
        soma += digitos[i] * (13 - i);
        soma2 += digitos[i + 1] * (13 - i);
    }
    soma += digitos[11] * 2;
    var resto = soma % 11;
    var dv = digitos[12];
    digitos[12] = resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - resto;
    soma2 += digitos[12] * 2;
    var ok = digitos[12] == dv;
    resto = soma2 % 11;
    dv = digitos[13];
    digitos[13] = resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - resto;
    return (ok && digitos[13] == dv, string.Concat(digitos[12], digitos[13]));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WjFZ7P). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JyREXe). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/CnpjValidation.cs).

Com ultra otimização:

```
using static System.Console;
using System;

(var ok, var digitos) = ValidarCnpj("12345678901234");
if (!ok) WriteLine($"Dígitos finais corretos seriam {digitos}");
(ok, digitos) = ValidarCnpj("12.345.678.9012-34");
if (!ok) WriteLine($"Dígitos finais corretos seriam {digitos}");

static (bool, string) ValidarCnpj(string cnpj) {
    if (cnpj.Length < 14) return (false, "");
    Span<int> digitos = stackalloc int[14];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 14; j++) if (char.IsDigit(cnpj[j])) digitos[i++] = cnpj[j] - 48;
    int soma = 0, soma2 = 0;
    soma += digitos[0] * 5;
    soma2 += digitos[0] * 6;
    soma += digitos[1] * 4;
    soma2 += digitos[1] * 5;
    soma += digitos[2] * 3;
    soma2 += digitos[2] * 4;
    soma += digitos[3] * 2;
    soma2 += digitos[3] * 3;
    soma += digitos[4] * 9;
    soma2 += digitos[4] * 2;
    soma += digitos[5] * 8;
    soma2 += digitos[5] * 9;
    soma += digitos[6] * 7;
    soma2 += digitos[6] * 8;
    soma += digitos[7] * 6;
    soma2 += digitos[7] * 7;
    soma += digitos[8] * 5;
    soma2 += digitos[8] * 6;
    soma += digitos[9] * 4;
    soma2 += digitos[9] * 5;
    soma += digitos[10] * 3;
    soma2 += digitos[10] * 4;
    soma += digitos[11] * 2;
    soma2 += digitos[11] * 3;
    var resto = soma % 11;
    var dv = digitos[12];
    digitos[12] = resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - resto;
    soma2 += digitos[12] * 2;
    var ok = digitos[12] == dv;
    resto = soma2 % 11;
    dv = digitos[13];
    digitos[13] = resto < 2 ? 0 : 11 - resto;
    return (ok && digitos[13] == dv, string.Concat(digitos[12], digitos[13]));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CDgjNe). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VtyvRf). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/CnpjValidation2.cs).

Dá para otimizar mais. Pode não compensar fazer o *unroll* manual. Há casos que ganha de um lado e perde de outro.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool IsCnpj(string cnpj)
    {
        int[] multiplicador1 = new int[12] {5,4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2};
        int[] multiplicador2 = new int[13] {6,5,4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2};
        int soma;
        int resto;
        string digito;
        string tempCnpj;

        cnpj = cnpj.Trim();
        cnpj = cnpj.Replace(".", "").Replace("-", "").Replace("/", "");

        if (cnpj.Length != 14)
           return false;

        tempCnpj = cnpj.Substring(0, 12);

        soma = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
           soma += int.Parse(tempCnpj[i].ToString()) * multiplicador1[i];

        resto = (soma % 11);
        if ( resto < 2)
           resto = 0;
        else
           resto = 11 - resto;

        digito = resto.ToString();

        tempCnpj = tempCnpj + digito;
        soma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
           soma += int.Parse(tempCnpj[i].ToString()) * multiplicador2[i];

        resto = (soma % 11);
        if (resto < 2)
            resto = 0;
        else
           resto = 11 - resto;

        digito = digito + resto.ToString();

        if cnpj.Right(2) <> digito
           MsgBox("CNPJ inválido, o Digito Verificador correto seria: "+digito);

        return cnpj.EndsWith(digito);
    }
```